# Eliminar strings que empiecen por determinados caracteres - Expresiones regulares Python

Tags: python, string, regex

estoy tratando de eliminar elementos de una frase que empiecen por determinados carácteres, por ahora lo estoy haciendo de la siguiente forma:

```
   # Eliminar elementos que empiecen por un determinado carácter:        
    eliminar_caracteres = ["@","#","htt"]
    for caracter in eliminar_caracteres:
        frase = re.sub(f'{caracter}\S+', '', frase)
```

y va perfecto, pero me gustaría aprender a hacerlo sin tener que iterar sobre cada elemento, he probado a hacerlo así:

```
caracteres = ["htt@#"]
frase = re.sub(f'{caracteres}\S+', '', frase)
frase
```

El problema es que aquí no reconoce bien que el "htt" va junto y me encuentro errores como el siguiente:

```
input: frase = "Hola paco has visto #esto https://www.youtube.com/?hl=es&gl=ES me voy a Teruel, visto"
output: 'Hola paco  vis   me voy a Teruel, vis'
```

¿Cómo puedo indicar que los carácteres en  ["htt@#"] van separados adecuadamente sin tener que iterar sobre ellos con un bucle?

Gracias, un saludo!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para obtener el mismo resultado que con el for, necesitas usar or (`|`). La expresión sería algo así:

```
'@\S+|#\S+|htt\S+'
```

Puedes agrupar `#`y `@` en una clase de caracteres ya que son caracteres sueltos, pero para `htt` necesitas si o si usar `|`.

Puedes construirla dinámicamente a partir de la lista usando formateo de cadenas, teniendo el debido cuidado:

```
import re

frase = "Hola paco has visto #esto https://www.youtube.com/?hl=es&gl=ES me voy a Teruel, visto"

eliminar_caracteres = ["@", "#", "htt"]
regex = re.compile("|".join(f"{cad}\S+" for cad in eliminar_caracteres))
frase = regex.sub("", frase)
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo de una manera muy sencilla con la siguiente expresión regular:

```
([@#]|htt).*?(?=[\s|$])
```

Por ejemplo:

```
import re

frase = "Hola paco has visto #esto https://www.youtube.com/?hl=es&gl=ES me voy a Teruel, visto"

frase = re.sub('([@#]|htt).*?(?=[\s|$])', '', frase)

print(frase)
```